# MATLAB solve a single equation

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve this equation: $e^x=x^e+e$ in MATLAB, but I continually get an error. I do not know where to go from here. Any help is appreciated This is what I have:

a = x^exp(1) + exp(1) == exp(x);
syms x
b = solve(a,x);
disp(b);

Comment: Initialise `x` before using it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell Matlab that $x$ is symbolic before you use it. Swap your first and second lines.

[image]

Comment: I did that and recieved this error: Error using sym/subsindex (line 737)
Invalid indexing or function definition. When defining a function, ensure that the arguments are symbolic variables and the body of
the function is a SYM expression. When indexing, the input must be numeric, logical, or ':'.

Comment: @Nate included an image to demonstrate with an approximate check.

Comment: @Nate Is it possible you've made a mistake elsewhere in your code? I can't see why you should have any problem.

Comment: Have you defined a variable called `exp`? Clear the workspace and run your code again.